# Canonical sheaf of complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ and $g$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ and $e$ in $n+1$ variables, and let $Y$ be the zeros of $f$ and $g$. Suppose $Y$ is smooth (so $Y$ is a smooth complete intersection). I would like to show the canonical sheaf $\Omega_{Y}$ is $\mathcal O_Y(d+e-n-1)$. Here's what I've got so far:

Notation: $$Y=Z(f, g) \overset{j}{\to}  X = Z(f) \overset{i}{\to} \mathbb P^n$$.

It suffices to check the two following sequences are exact (maps explained in the link below):
$$0 \to \mathcal O_X(-d) \to i^*\Omega_{\mathbb P^n} \to \Omega_X \to 0$$
$$0 \to \mathcal O_Y(-e) \to j^*\Omega_{X} \to \Omega_Y \to 0$$

The first sequence would be exact by Lemma 7.4.16 [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf#page=139) but I must have that that $X$ is smooth. In general, even if $Y$ is smooth, $X$ need not be smooth (for example take $Z(xy, x-y) \subset Z(xy)$). How can I get around this? Thanks.

Comment: Why is $Z(xy,x-y)$ smooth? Any way, smoothness is not necessary, but if $X$ is smooth and if one is over an infinite filed, Bertini will ensure that you can choose $f,g$, to get the appropriate smoothness.

Comment: Here are a few more details of ways to get around this from Eisenbud's and Harris's new book: https://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf#page=63